# How to convert a cdata type to bytes?

Tags: python-3.x, byte, cdata

How can I convert a cdata type to bytes? I have a cdata type of

> cdata 'secp256k1_pubkey *' owning 64 bytes

And I need to convert this to a byte hex.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python, try this code:

```
bytes(ffi.buffer(pubkey, 32))
```